# Ubuntu 12.4 vbox guest cannot bridge to windows 8 host network adapter

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-8

I running Ubuntu 12.4 guest in windows 8 host.

It seems that Ubuntu vbox adapter cannot bridge to the host adapter and so cannot access the internet.

In fact, there seems to be no network at all even if I change the adapter to internal only.

Is there any workaround for this? I have spent hours and hours trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one adapter in your host (for instance a WiFi & Ethernet adapter), you need to select the one that is actually providing internet connectivity.